# How can i add custom header in authorize swagger ui?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, swagger, swashbuckle

As shown in the code below, it is implemented in the Web API Project in .NET, and tokens can be issued in the swagger through login like an image.

But I need a custom input box in OAuth2.0 besides client_id and client_secret. The purpose of the custom input box is to use in the header.

Is there any way to add an input box in the attached image window to use the input value as a header value?

The custom header will not be used in all APIs I have developed, but will only be used in OAuth2.0 authentication as in the image.

[image: the oauth form]

```cs
    public static void AddSwaggerDocumentation(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
        {
            option.AddSecurityDefinition("OAuth2.0", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                {
                    ClientCredentials = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                    {
                        TokenUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:7154/api/login")
                    }
                }
            });

            option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference()
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        },
                        Scheme = "Bearer",
                        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                        Name = "Bearer",
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header
                    }, new List<string>()
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

This is just an idea that came to my mind I hope it helps you
Just try it may not be certain it will be in your own code ;

To add a custom input box for OAuth2.0 authentication in Swagger UI, you can follow these steps:

Customize Swagger UI: You will need to customize the Swagger UI interface to include an additional input field for your custom header value.

Modify OAuth2.0 Configuration: You should also update your OAuth2.0 configuration to include the custom header using the value entered by the user.

Customize Swagger UI:

Locate the Swagger UI source code in your .NET project. This is often found in a folder like "wwwroot/swagger" or a similar location.
In the Swagger UI HTML file (typically index.html or similar), you'll need to add an HTML input element for your custom header value. For example:

```
<input type="text" id="customHeader" placeholder="Custom Header Value">
```

Modify the JavaScript code to capture the value entered by the user when making an OAuth2.0 request. You can use JavaScript to fetch this value from the input field you added.
Modify OAuth2.0 Configuration:

In your OAuth2.0 configuration (the code you provided in your question), update it to include the custom header using the value entered by the user.
Here's a simplified example of how you can modify the OAuth2.0 configuration to include the custom header :

```
public static void AddSwaggerDocumentation(this IServiceCollection 
                                             services)
 {
       services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
   {
      option.AddSecurityDefinition("OAuth2.0", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
      {
         Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            ClientCredentials = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                TokenUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:7154/api/login"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    // Define your OAuth2.0 scopes here
                }
            }
        }
    });

    option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference()
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                },
                Scheme = "Bearer",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                Name = "Bearer",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            }, new List<string>()
        },
        // Add your custom header here using the value entered by the 
        user
        {
            "CustomHeader", // This should match the name of your custom 
             header
            new List<string>()
        }
    });
});}
```

Please note that this is a simplified example, and you'll need to adapt it to your specific requirements.
You should also validate and sanitize user input to ensure security.
Additionally, you'll need to adjust your API code to handle the custom header appropriately

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

However, the Swagger UI source code does not exist in the Web API Project.

In my project, I simply declare by adding the Swashbuckle package.

Also, the code example you gave me has an error and it is difficult to implement.

```csharp
        // Add your custom header here using the value entered by the 
        user
        {
            "CustomHeader", // This should match the name of your custom 
             header
            new List<string>()
        }
```

Comment: Not working for me either. Try a various different configurations that I can think of but no luck.